# page margins not respected after A3 page insertion in A4 document

Tags: margins, koma-script, geometry, paper-size

I am inserting an A3 page in an A4 document but the margins are not respected (and neither does a page number appear), after the A3 page.

Test code below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,pagesize]{report}
\usepackage{nextpage}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\afterpage{ % Insert after the current page
\clearpage

\KOMAoptions{paper=a3} 
\recalctypearea

A3 stuff

\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
}

\clearpage    

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can add a new margin geometry with your [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/geometry) package and your `\newgeometry` command.  It's all in the package's documentation.  You can later restore it with `\restoregeometry`

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to point out: If you use `\KOMAoptions`, you should also be using a `KOMA-script` documentclass, such as `scrreprt` instead of `report`

Comment: @MarioS.E. When I try to add \newgeometry (or \savegeometry, \loadgeometry, \restoregeometry) in the above code I get '! Undefined control sequence.'

Comment: You'll have to read the `geometry` package documentation to get the full details, but it goes something like this `\newgeometry{outer=25mm,inner=35mm,vmargin=20mm,includehead,includefoot,headheight=15pt} ... \restoregeometry`

Answer (score 2):

Changing the page layout and geometry inside `\afterpage` is a little pushing.

I think a robust way for inserting A3 pages is a new document for the A3 stuff.
Then it can be included via package `pdfpages`:

```
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
% ...
\begin{document}
  % ...
  \afterpage{%
    \includepdf[fitpaper,pages=-]{a3.pdf}%
  }
  % ...
\end{document}
```