# Change the margin in A3 page, using KOMA script

Tags: margins, koma-script, width

I have a very large image to be inserted in an A3 page in a A4 page book. I have used KOMA script for A3 page inserted.

```
\afterpage{% Insert after the current page
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,paper=landscape,pagesize}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-2.0cm}
\recalctypearea
\begin{figure}[p]
\includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth] Sample.png}%
\caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
```

Now the image appears mostly to the left margin and a lot of space on the right is left blank. When I tried changing the width more than textwidth, the box around the image stayed at the same place and the image stretched.

Is there any method to change the textwidth or change the margin values?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Whether or not `\recalctypearea` makes sense in this case, depends on the current setting of `DIV`. Mostly it doesn't make sense. And also changing `\hoffset` seems to be strange. But I need a MWE to say more about this. I would prefer either usage of a large `DIV` value or using `\areaset`. And I would use `\storeareas` (see chapter 20 of the KOMA-Script manual scrguien.pdf) to save and restore the settings of the A4 page.

Comment: Related: [page margins not respected after A3 page insertion in A4 document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179814/page-margins-not-respected-after-a3-page-insertion-in-a4-document), [Page break problem after changing the page format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344797/page-break-problem-after-changing-the-page-format), [A0 (landscape) sheet inside A4 paper](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204772/a0-landscape-sheet-inside-a4-paper)